# How to organize the htdocs folder when a wordpress installation is present?

Tags: php, wordpress, dreamweaver, mamp, flash-cs5

I've been told by many tutorials (including the official wordpress tutorials) that I need to place all the files (in the wordpress folder) into the htdocs folder (without a sub-directory).

I'm using MAMP for my PHP environment and Dreamweaver CS5 to build the websites. The problem that I am having is that I want to create a new project in Dreamweaver that is not using wordpress, but because all those wordpress files are in the htdocs without a sub-directory, it is giving me all sorts of warnings that issues could occur if I place a directory for my new project in the htdocs folder along side all those other files.

I've tried putting all the wordpress files into a folder called "wordpress" under htdocs, but that breaks it and I've been told not to do that but not why I shouldn't do that.

How can I organize my htdocs folder so I can have more than one project present in that directory?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In local machine, you can be well sure of yourself that you need to organize each project of yours in a folder in the "`htdocs`" directory. This is of utmost importance to keep all the projects nicely so that you can later on reference all your projects easily.

When "*tutorials are saying that you need to place all the files (in the `WordPress` folder) into the `htdocs` folder (without a sub-directory)*", they mostly mean about the live server & not about the development server.

Also please check the ".htaccess" file of the root directory of each project, for the "**Site URL**" or the "**Rewrite Base**", when you are configuring multiple projects in the "`htdocs`" folder, so that each of the projects run smoothly. And you should also check that each project is running smoothly, which have been kept in the "`htdocs`" folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So basically I can put my wordpress files into a sub-directory in the htdocs folder and the only thing it will affect is the live-view aspect of Dreamweaver will not be functional?

Comment: I'm also getting this error now and have no idea where it came from: "Dynamically-related files are not resolved because of an Internal Server Error." Any idea what could cause that? - It's happening in Dreamweaver when I try to discover files that are dynamically related to the index.php file...

Comment: Check whether you have got the Apache "`mod_redirect`" extension enabled in your local machine.

Comment: By **live environment**, I meant about the client's main server.